# SQL- Mutually exclusive JOIN based on reservation and item production date (user/item must not appear multiple times in the result set)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have two tables ***order*** and ***item*** and I need to match orders and items and the match is given by the column **match** and I need to make sure the customer who orders first will receive the item first (oldest reservation date gets the product first).

Also, the company prefers to send the oldest items first i.e oldest production date;

Practical example:

**order table:**

| user | match | reservation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| alan | vz123 | 01/22 |
| maria | vz123 | 02/22 |
| doug | vz123 | 03/22 |

**item table**

| item_id | match | production_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | vz123 | 03/22 |
| Y | vz123 | 02/22 |

The problem is when joining by the match column (item specs) I'm getting 1-N results;

The final result I want is:

| user | item_id | reservation_date | production_date | match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alan | Y | 01/22 | 02/22 | vz123 |
| maria | X | 02/22 | 03/22 | vz123 |

Note that neither user nor item_id appears in the result set more than once and we are giving preferences based on dates;

- Company prefers to fulfill orders based on reservation date (oldest first)
- Company prefers to sell items based on production date ("production gate date", oldest first)

Is this possible in SQL (SQL server, postgres...)?

Comment: `01/22` This is NOT a date! Make an effort. What happens when "dates" of your rows span more than a year? And will the very reliable programmer (or application) that is adding rows always include a leading zero for months before October (of any year)?

Comment: @SMor this is just a mock example of my data (for sake of time and simplicity I did not put days...) but thanks for the heads up. I just wanted to know if it is possible to handle reservation dates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a window function ROW_NUMBER, to determine which row of the order is relevant to the item row

One problem you need to adress, that you have to mark the rows that are already processed.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders  (
>   "user" VARCHAR(5),
>   "match" VARCHAR(5),
>   "reservation_date" VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO orders 
>   ("user", "match", "reservation_date")
> VALUES
>   ('alan', 'vz123', '01/22'),
>   ('maria', 'vz123', '02/22'),
>   ('doug', 'vz123', '03/22');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE item  (
>   "item_id" VARCHAR(1),
>   "match" VARCHAR(5),
>   "production_date" VARCHAR(5)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO item 
>   ("item_id", "match", "production_date")
> VALUES
>   ('X', 'vz123', '03/22'),
>   ('Y', 'vz123', '02/22');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
> "user","item_id","reservation_date","production_date",o."match"
> FROM
> (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "match" ORDER BY  "reservation_date" ASC) rn FROM orders) o
> JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "match" ORDER BY  "production_date" ASC) rn FROM item) i
> ON i."match" = o."match" AND o.rn = i.rn
> ```
>
> ```
> user  | item_id | reservation_date | production_date | match
> :---- | :------ | :--------------- | :-------------- | :----
> alan  | Y       | 01/22            | 02/22           | vz123
> maria | X       | 02/22            | 03/22           | vz123
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=083307d91e0d1a5c18f1081ae601eae7)*

Comment: A date as a VARCHAR? Are you sure? Why do you want so many (future) problems?

Comment: the date is no valid date in postgres so i am forced to use characters, but it doesn't matter as you only  need the correct sorting and this is garateed